# Removing subdoc with express and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I would like to remove a subdoc from a mongoDB user. However, the Mongoose docs that cover the remove function seem light, and as such, my function returns the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

What's going wrong in this piece of code? How do I make the subdoc id accessible so the function can remove it?

```
// Remove a destination from the user
router.get('/delete', function(req, res, next) {
  var subdoc = User.destinations.id(_id).remove()
  user.save(function (err) {
    if (err) return handleError (err)
  })
})
```

Jade template

```
  each dest in user.destinations
    .destination
      li= dest.airport
      li= dest.daysAway 
      li= dest.day
      li= dest.month
      a(href='/delete') Delete this entry
```

Comment: share your schema or response

Answer (score 1):

**User** is a mongoose model. It's a collection of user docs. every user doc in User collection has a subdoc named *destinations*; so *destinations* is placed on every user not on User model.

You first should find the related user doc then remove your desired destination from its destinations subdoc:

```
// Remove a destination from the user
router.get('/delete/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  // Find the user
  User.findById(req.user._id, function(err, user) {
     if ( user ) {
       // Find subdoc
       var subdoc = user.destinations.id(req.params.id);
       // Remove subdoc
       subdoc.remove();
       // Save user
       user.save(function (err) {
         if (err) return handleError(err);
       });             
     }
  });
});
```

Jade template:

```
  each dest in user.destinations
    .destination
      li= dest.airport
      li= dest.daysAway 
      li= dest.day
      li= dest.month
      a(href='/delete/' + dest._id ) Delete this entry
```

Here i assume you have your user mounted on `request` as result of authentication process so we can get it's id through `req.user._id`. If not you should somehow find your user, so you can find it using `findById` or `findOne` methods of mongoose model.

Also i added `dest.id` in template so we can find related destination by its id using `req.params.id`

**Note** that you could use [*method-override*](https://github.com/expressjs/method-override) middleware and use *DELETE* method instead of GET in a more standard manner.

Answer (score 0):

After stumbling through pieces of code across the Internet I found this solution which is quite eloquent I think.

```
router.get('/delete/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  User.update(
    { "_id": req.user.id },
    { "$pull": { "destinations": { "_id": req.params.id } } },
      function(err, numAffected) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            res.status(200).send()
            res.redirect('/')
        }
      }
    )
});
```